# Integrating Unity3D code into SWIFT issue

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, unity-game-engine

I have Swift application, and I need to integrate Unity 3D code in it (when compile Unity code, it compiles like Xcode project). It seemed quite easy, because Unity application gets converted into Xcode application, so I can launch new Unity project from Xcode (converted unity project). But integration is quite difficult with changes in Xcode settings, so I can’t find out what to do.

I do everything according to instructions of 
https://the-nerd.be/2015/08/20/a-better-way-to-integrate-unity3d-within-a-native-ios-application/ and
https://github.com/blitzagency/ios-unity5

But I always get errors

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

“il2cpp::icalls::mscorlib::System::Char::GetDataTablePointers(unsigned char const**, unsigned char const**, double const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**, unsigned short const**)”, referenced from:

"il2cpp::os::WindowsRuntime::CreateHString(il2cpp::utils::StringView const&, Il2CppHString__**)", referenced from:

“il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalFreeBString(unsigned short*)”, referenced from:

“il2cpp::vm::PlatformInvoke::MarshalCppBStringToCSharpStringResult(unsigned short const*)”, referenced from:

Any idea why its happening?

Comment: I got solution after struggle of hours. Changing 'C Language Dialect' to C99[-std=c99] in Build Settings works.